# How to do an MCA analysis on a binary dataset?

Tags: python, linear-regression, pca

I've asked this question on stack exchange, but no luck.

I'm looking to do an EDA with some binary data as seen below and I was recommended to use MCA. However, I'm not sure about how to go about doing this in a meaningful way. I'm looking to find key variables that positively influence and negatively influence a dependent variable. I'm currently using python. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 3 | column 3 | Dependent variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any code, just this dataset. There is about a 10k rows of data. I would like to find the relationship of each column to the dependent variable and to see if its significantly influential or not.